# No current bean manager found in CDI service in websphere 9

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.1, websphere-9

I am migrating from WAS 8 to WAS 9.
my application uses Hibernate 4.3.0.Beta3 version and spring 4.0.3. 
At the time of application start up I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred in the org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider persistence
    provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for 
    the AccidentCompensation persistence unit. The following error occurred: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
    No current bean manager found in CDI service
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.cdi.impl.BeanManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(BeanManagerInvocationHandler.java:80)
```

Please let me know if need more information.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem write a custom session builder and disable beanreference from factory instance.

```java
package br.com.temasistemas.utils.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.boot.SessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataImplementor;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryBuilderFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryBuilderImplementor;

public class CustomSessionFactoryBuilderFactory implements SessionFactoryBuilderFactory {

    @Override
    public SessionFactoryBuilder getSessionFactoryBuilder(final MetadataImplementor metadata,
            final SessionFactoryBuilderImplementor defaultBuilder) {
        return defaultBuilder.applyBeanManager(null);
    }

}
```

create a service file:

```
META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryBuilderFactory
```

edit the file as text file and add the content:

```
br.com.temasistemas.utils.hibernate.CustomSessionFactoryBuilderFactory
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But how to disable beanreference from factory instance.
And i am using persistence.xml file for configuration.